# code problem finding id and index

Tags: android

new to programming and android, so I really have no idea what im doing. can anyone tell me why this code returns incorrect values of -1 for index and a 10 digit number for id, when I clearly assign an id and the index should not be -1 because its 0 based??

I would think that the problem is somewhere in the code that gets the focused view, but ive tried findFocus and getCurrentFocus, and both return the same thing. Here is the code, thanks!

```
llmain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutMain);
    linflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int pos = 0;

    View myView = linflater.inflate(R.layout.action, null);
    myView.setId(pos);
    pos++;
    llmain.addView(myView);
    myView.requestFocus();
    View v = getCurrentFocus();
    if(v instanceof EditText) {
       id = v.getId();
       index = llmain.indexOfChild(v);
       Context context = getApplicationContext();
       CharSequence text = "index is:" + index + "id is:" + id;
       int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
       toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: When is this code run? If it's during `onCreate` then focus may not have been assigned yet...furthermore, `requestFocus` is not guaranteed to immediately grant focus.

Comment: You should check the return value of `requestFocus` to determine that it succeeded. Also, `indexOfChild` returns `-1` when the argument is not a child view.

Answer (score 1):

In android a Views Id is a Long that is a unique Identifier for that View. It is best not to reference by using this number but instead to use R.id.viewIdSuppliedInLayout that way you can use descriptive text instead of trying to keep straight which numbers point to which views. If you are creating dynamic views like you appear to be doing it will be assigned an Id, you shouldn't have to set it. In your inflate() method you should pass R.id.actionsRootViewID as the second parameter. My gut instinct is that this is why indexOf is returning -1, because it can't find the view that you are looking for. 0 would be the first view in the layout, since it isn't finding your view it needs to let you know somehow that it failed to find, so they chose to have it return -1 to indicate this.

Comment: if I try to pass R.id.actionsRootViewID as the second parameter, it wants to change its type in R to ViewGroup, which in turn causes an error there due to the fact that its supposed to be an int... is there no simpler way to get the id and index of a selected or focused edittext that has been dynamically created? I agree that its having a problem finding the view im seeking.